# Preloading 'belongs to' associations both ways

Tags: go, associations, one-to-one, go-gorm

I'd like to use GORM's ['belongs to' association](http://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html) in a way similar to [Django's one-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/). Consider the following example in which each `User` is associated with one `Profile`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

func (user User) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("User(Name=%s)", user.Name)
}

type Profile struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID uint
    User   User
    Name   string
}

func (profile Profile) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Profile(Name=%s, User=%d)", profile.Name, profile.UserID)
}

func (user *User) AfterCreate(scope *gorm.Scope) error {
    profile := Profile{
        UserID: user.ID,
        Name:   user.Name,
    }

    return scope.DB().Create(&profile).Error
}

const dbName = "examplegorm.db"

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", dbName)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("open db: %v", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        db.Close()
        os.Remove(dbName)
    }()

    db.LogMode(true)
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Profile{})

    user := User{Name: "jinzhu"}
    if err := db.Create(&user).Error; err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("create user: %v", err)
    }

    var profile Profile
    if err := db.Where(Profile{UserID: user.ID}).Preload("User").First(&profile).Error; err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("get profile: %v", err)
    }

    logrus.Infof("profile: %v", profile)
    logrus.Infof("user: %v", profile.User)
}
```

In this example, I query for a `Profile` and preload its `User`. I would actually like to do this the other way, however: query a `User` and preload its `Profile`.

As I understand it, in Django you would be able to access both the `profile.user` and the `user.profile`, but if I try to add `Profile` and `ProfileID` fields to the `User` model,

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Profile
    ProfileID uint
}
```

I get an 'invalid recursive type' error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./gorm_belongs_to.go:23:6: invalid recursive type Profile
```

Is there any way to get a `user.Profile` in this GORM example?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem in your case is using the name `Profile` which is the same as the type.
If your `User` struct will look something like this it should work:

```
 type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    UserProfile Profile
    UserProfileID uint
}
```

Comment: That still results in the same error message, `invalid recursive type Profile`.